# Show git diff with GITG on Fedora

Tags: git, fedora, gitg

I am using this tool https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/ as a git GUI.

In Ubuntu when I open the application inside a git project is shows the unstaged/unadded files in the top left and I can easily see the diff.

But in Fedora I cannot see the modified files, in the left menu I just see the branches, remote branches and tags.

How can I see the diff with gitg in Fedora? or is there another better tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the "Staging area" in the top-right corner:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh yeah, I was always looking at the top-left like it is on Ubuntu, thanks!

Comment: Without reading your comment, I don't think I could have found it :)